# Python pandas cannot read old excel files with some strange encoding and split panes

Tags: python, excel, encoding, pandas

I am trying to import an old excel file into pandas. The file is generated by the cropSyst software using an old format (which I don't know) and it has split panes by default. This is a snapshot

[image: excel preview]

A solution could be to open the file with excel and save it in xlsx: this way pandas can read it with no problem, but I have to deal with a large number of files (> 40000) so it's not feasible.

when trying to import it with pandas

```
pd.read_excel(filename)
```

I get this error

```
error: unpack requires a string argument of length 3
*** No CODEPAGE record, no encoding_override: will use 'ascii'
```

I tried also to import it as csv

```
pd.read_csv(filename)
```

but it reads only some data, I tried using different combinations of line separators and cell delimiters with no luck.

[image: data read from csv parser]

do you have some suggestions?

**EDIT**

As suggested by @jmcnamara in the comments I tried to override the encoding of the file using all the encodings available in Python, but still no luck: it does not parse correctly the file.

Here is possible to download one of the xls files

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5smcFuBd6EtdFE5eEktZXZVTkU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The file may not be in Excel BIFF format. Could you add the output of the unix utility `file file.xls` to see what format it is in. Also, the output of the following might be helpful: `xxd -l 64 file.xls`.

Comment: Thanks @jmcnamara, the output of `file file.xls` is


`Applesoft BASIC program data`


while the output of `xxd -l 64 file.xls` is


`0000000: 0908 0600 0000 1000 0000 0002 0a00 0000  ................
0000010: 4d00 0000 0001 0000 0400 1700 0000 0000  M...............
0000020: 0000 010e 4861 7276 6573 7420 7265 706f  ....Harvest repo
0000030: 7274 0004 0012 0001 0000 0000 0001 0920  rt.............`

Comment: That looks like the Excel 4 file format which xlrd (which is used by Pandas) should be able to read. The Codepage error means that the file has no CODEPAGE record so xlrd cannot determine the encoding type. You may be able to work around it by specifying the `encoding_override` in `xlrd.open_workbook()` (and then in Pandas).

Comment: thanks for your comment: I tried with all python encodings, as listed in https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html, but it cannot parse correctly the file. Do you have a particular encoding to suggest or something else?

Comment: What error do you get if you use an encoding such as `ascii`? Also, could you make one of the files, with non-sensitive data, available for debugging.

Comment: executing the command `open_workbook(filename, encoding_override='ascii')` returns the following error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)`. The link to the file is now at the bottom of the question and is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5smcFuBd6EtdFE5eEktZXZVTkU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format of the file is Excel 2 (BIFF2).

However, since it wasn't created by Excel it seems to contain inconsistencies with the Excel BIFF2 spec.

For the file you show the WINDOW2 record is incorrect. You can workaround this by getting the current version of `xlrd` (0.9.3) and applying the following patch:

```
diff --git a/xlrd/sheet.py b/xlrd/sheet.py
index 36438a0..6d895c4 100644
--- a/xlrd/sheet.py
+++ b/xlrd/sheet.py
@@ -1455,7 +1455,8 @@ class Sheet(BaseObject):
                     (self.first_visible_rowx, self.first_visible_colx,
                     self.automatic_grid_line_colour,
                     ) = unpack("<HHB", data[5:10])
-                    self.gridline_colour_rgb = unpack("<BBB", data[10:13])
+                    if data_len > 10:
+                        self.gridline_colour_rgb = unpack("<BBB", data[10:13])
                     self.gridline_colour_index = nearest_colour_index(
                         self.book.colour_map, self.gridline_colour_rgb, debug=0)
                     self.cached_page_break_preview_mag_factor = 0 # default (60%)
```

Then install this version of the module or use it from your `PYTHONPATH` since pandas uses `xlrd` to read Excel files.

This still gives the Codepage warning but that is only a warning and you can use `encoding_override='ascii'` (or whatever the correct encoding is but ascii is probably right).

Note, there may other issues in the file format, given that you have 40,000 files, but that was the only one I found in the file you provided.

**Update**: Based on the second example file it looks like the encoding is Windows CP-1252 so the following should work:

```
import xlrd 

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('harvest.xls', encoding_override='cp1252')
```

Comment: thanks a lot @jmcnamara, indeed your solution worked. I have just two types of excel files within the 40000, the other one is still not working with your solution. I already marked your solution as the correct one, since it is, but if you want to have a look to the other file and maybe solve it, I would be very happy ;-) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5smcFuBd6EtU2JZamdzdlVKTjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you have no idea about the time you saved me. We're talking about days. Thanks again, you've been very kind, and extremely useful!

Answer (score 1):

I've previously used this with success to open old Excel files, give it a try:

http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: thanks for your answer: it still giving encoding errors (I tried with several encodings). Do you have a particular encoding to suggest?

Comment: have you looked at the [xlrd docs](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966)?