# Pandas can't read excel encoding

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I'm trying to import an excel file into Pandas. I'm using `df=pd.read_excel(file_path)` but it keeps getting me this error:

```
*** No CODEPAGE record, no encoding_override: will use 'ascii'
*** No CODEPAGE record, no encoding_override: will use 'ascii'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/PycharmProjects/KlooksExplore/FindCos/FindCos_Functions.py", line 5468, in <module>
    adjust_sheet(y1,y2,y3)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/PycharmProjects/KlooksExplore/FindCos/FindCos_Functions.py", line 5130, in adjust_sheet
    y1=pd.read_excel(y1)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 230, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 294, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(self._io)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 162, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 119, in open_workbook_xls
    bk.get_sheets()
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 719, in get_sheets
    self.get_sheet(sheetno)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 710, in get_sheet
    sh.read(self)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/sheet.py", line 815, in read
    strg = unpack_string(data, 6, bk.encoding or bk.derive_encoding(), lenlen=2)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/biffh.py", line 249, in unpack_string
    return unicode(data[pos:pos+nchars], encoding)
  File "/Users/santanna_santanna/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/timemachine.py", line 30, in <lambda>
    unicode = lambda b, enc: b.decode(enc)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The file I'm trying to import is [this one](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19K8q2ljTTFnHaGrYE5zg2VSE8ms8pSq0/view?usp=sharing).
Is that an encoding problem or some character in the file is causing this? What would be the way to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried including  `encoding = utf-16`?

Comment: tried both utf-8 and utf-16. if you download the file you will see it doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970422/python-pandas-cannot-read-old-excel-files-with-some-strange-encoding-and-split-p

Answer (score 1):

@astrobiologist gave a good hint

Since I didn't want the hassle of going into patches, the way I found to solve was to open the file in Open Office and save it as an Excel 97 file. Finally worked

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.read_excel('data.csv' encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: thanks @astrobiologist, however is doesn't work, same problem happens.

Comment: this might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970422/python-pandas-cannot-read-old-excel-files-with-some-strange-encoding-and-split-p

Comment: pd.read_excel() doesn't have the `encoding` argument.